# Copying a document to another collection server-side

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any way to copy or move a document from one collection to another, on the database server, without sending the document to the client?

In SQL, this can be achieved with something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (f1, f2)
SELECT f1, f2 FROM table2 WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the aggregation framework's [`$out` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/). The following example will copy documents from the books collection to the authors collection:

```javascript
db.books.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } },
    { $out: "authors" }
]);
```